# Get Exception Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory with CXF 2.7.11 JAX-RS

Tags: cxf, weblogic11g

I am try to use `CXF 2.7.11` and Spring to develop Restfull web service. get this Cannot create a secure `XMLInputFactory` when try to implement `JAX-RS` Security

```
Caused By:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create a secure XMLInputFactory

at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:314)

at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.getXMLInputFactory(StaxUtils.java:264)

at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1549)

at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.read(StaxUtils.java:1122)

at 

org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.spring.JettySpringTypesFactory.createTLSServerParametersMap(JettyS
pringTypesFactory.java:101)   

WEB-INF/lib floder contain the following jar 
asm-3.3.1.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

commons-lang-2.6.jar

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

commons-logging-1.1.jar

cxf-2.7.11.jar

cxf-bundle-jaxrs-2.7.11.jar

cxf-manifest.jar

geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar

geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar

geronimo-jaxws_2.2_spec-1.1.jar


geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar

geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.3.jar

javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar

jaxb-api-2.2.5.jar

jaxb-impl-2.2.5.1.jar

jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar

jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar

neethi-3.0.3.jar

ojdbc6.jar

spring-aop-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-beans-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-context-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-expression-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-jdbc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-jms-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-tx-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

spring-web-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar

stax2-api-3.1.4.jar

woodstox-core-asl-4.2.1.jar

wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar
```

Comment: You should show the code that is causing this exception in your question.

Comment: which app-server are you using?